# Variables are not updated in timer completion block

Tags: swift, timer, updates, completion

**Here is the scenario:**

I want to scroll(or shake) a horizontal collectionView after a page showing up so user could see it scrolling...

I do it with no problem 3 sec after page pops up but I don't want it to do the dance when user reach the collectionView before 2 sec & scrolls it itself.

**So here is my solution for it:**

```
   var collectionDidScroll = false

   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        collectionDidScroll = true
   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(showScrollTutorial), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
   }

   @objc func showScrollTutorial() {
        if !collectionDidScroll {
            collectionView.shakeCells()
        }
   }
```

**The Problem:**

The "collectionDidScroll" is update just fine in class, but in timer completion its always false!
It means "collectionDidScroll" is not updating in completion & it has its launch time value.

**Notice:**

My class is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell

I even tried dispatchQueue with timer & timer with completion block but the results are the same

Comment: If it is a `UICollectionViewCell` subClass then this method `scrollViewDidScroll` is never called so you will always get `collectionDidScroll` as `false`.

Comment: `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` works with a subclass of `UIScrollviewDelegate` and also make sure you set `scrollView.delegate = self`

Comment: Dear @Kamran &  NSCoder, scrollViewDidScroll is calling just fine & delegation is set as well.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`? Otherwise the user might still be scrolling and the function will not be called in time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved!**

I placed 'showScrollTutorial()' function contents inside a 'DispatchQueue' to force it to run in main thread, now it works like a charm!

Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above answered your question, but to help you tackle similar problems in the future yourself:

Whenever you have problems like this, you should try littering your code (especially `scrollViewDidScroll` and `showScrollTutorial`) with print-statements to see if they get called at all and which values they contain. Or you can set breakpoints!

Comment: Yes, and I did that and I found out the problem is this: no matter what I do, the variable in showScrollTutorial function is not updating! seems it fires right after controller launch! its crazy but it happens!